# Selectable digital communcation links between any two of eight devices

Tags: digital-communications, matrix

I'm building a small computer where I have 8 units that need to communicate with each other.
Each unit also has eight serial 6 Mbps async lines, so 16 pins.

The driver I'm looking for should be able to tie a specific input pin to a specific output pin with very low latency (I'm aiming for max 10 ns Tpd), and should work at 3.3 V or 5 V.

Something like this:

[image]

Does this kind of integrated circuit exist/have a name?

Comment: How many simultaneous links do you need? If only one, it's easy: one multiplexer and one demultiplexer. If two or three, still doable. If up to 32 simultaneous, then you need a matrix, and that becomes complicated and expensive.

Comment: Is the 10 ns the latency in an already connected channel? Or is it the speed of swicthing channels?

Comment: It's the speed of an already connected channel

Comment: I'm not looking for a single chip anyway . i can use more of them

Comment: Maybe you could use a CPLD or FPGA and "make" what you need.

Comment: @Rodo yes in the end i  may use those , but i'm looking for a simpler solution

Comment: How can we know if something suitable exists, as you don't give out any electrical details about your signals, so we can't know what is suitable for your signals?

Comment: @Justme The signals are square wave , 6 MHz , and i expect them to be at 3.3V or 5V

Comment: Please add any new information to the question.

Comment: @DavideAndrea 64 simultaneos links , knowing that there are 128 pins

Comment: Sounds like a crossbar switch is what you need. Make a physical one with signal relays if you need low signal latency through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL,DR: Forget the whole boondoggle. Use a *single* 100MBit raw Ethernet link from each node to an Ethernet switch. Plenty enough microcontrollers implement that on-board, or can be easily interfaced to external MAC-PHY chips via SPI.

---

The 10ns tpd requirement is not necessary for 6Mbps serial data. As long as the edges have good transition times, even 50ns would be fine.

The circuit to tie any combination of pins together is called a crossbar switch, and excellent ones exist. For example this [16x16 AD75019 crossbar](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad75019.html). It can switch signals all the way to the supply rails, so no problem with 3.3V or 5V level logic signals.

But the *real* problem I think is not the switch. That's easy. The *routing* is the hard part. Do you really want to be sending commands to a switch each time the routing changes? Or do you just want to send a packet with an address in the header and ensure it gets to its destination? That would make the rest of the circuit much simpler, since the *data* would be self-steering, and the crossbar could be considered a "black box".

But at that point, what's the use of 6Mbps? You may as well have 8 x 10BASET links on each device. Each link is bidirectional and full-duplex. An off-the-shelf ethernet switch with 64 ports would do the crossbar duties. It's the cheapest solution to implement if you insist on having 8 links on each device, I think. Connecting cables are cheap, connectors are cheap, interface logic is cheap, and the firmware development cost is only borne once.

Many microcontrollers can send pre-encoded 10BASET ethernet using nothing but GPIO (bit-banged, with DMA for transmission/reception), and the de-serialization for the receive side can also usually be done (with oversampling) using built-in peripherals. The RP2040 microcontroller has high-speed state machines that can do both tasks, although not enough to do both transmission and reception on 8 links. Transmission bit-banging would need to be done in software and then via DMA to GPIO.

Since this would be a "closed" solution, Ethernet isolation would not be needed. You can interface to 10BASET TXD with a resistor pair, and to 10BASET RXD with a cheap differential receiver (like for very fast RS485).

If you wanted to, you could have a dedicated interface MCU that converts between the serial 6Mbps data streams and 10BASET. Parallax Propeller II would do that job admirably. The serial data format could have a simple 8- or 7-bit address in the first byte, that the controller would translate back-and-forth to a fixed local Ethernet address.

But, at that point the whole thing is ridiculous anyway. Instead of 8x6MBps links on each microcontroller, just use a **single** 100MBps link, and send raw Ethernet packets out. An 8-port gigabit switch will gladly switch them to their destinations, and buffer if there would be collisions.

If you *don't* want to use 100MBps Ethernet, then you could use an external legacy SERDES chip (TI makes them, for example) to convert 10Mbytes/s 12-bit data into a serial stream that can be then switched using a custom switch in an FPGA or perhaps Propeller II, and then converted back to parallel data on the receiving end. That's *much simpler* than 8 paralleled connections as well.

---

I wonder if you actually have an MCU with 8 UARTS each running at 6MBps. Perhaps you're bit-banging stuff using a byte-wide GPIO port? If you are, then *parallel* transmission with header-routed data would be way simpler to implement. Due to the latency you'd expect in any reasonable microcontroller-controlled switching fabric, there'd be no benefit to parallel streams, and the firmware would be also way simpler on each node, since there'd be less data wrangling needed to encode and decode it, i.e. no merging of data streams, etc.

Comment: Im using 8 uarts at full speed as each units has multiple cores . In my idea , the links were supposed to change accordingly to the management done by the firmware . Now it's all more clear , appreciate your help !

Comment: It'd probably be easier to stick an SPI-to-Ethernet module for each core, and let an ethernet switch do the switching. Very popular modules use the WizNet W5500 chip. It supports SPI up to 80MHz, and 10/100BASET Ethernet. You could lower the per-packet latency dramatically compared to 6MBps if you went that route. The modules are cheap - a couple dollars each, and the chip itself is easy to add to your device board. It should be no problem I hope to use SPI instead of UART. W5500 lets you send and receive UDP and raw Ethernet frames - perfect for fast inter-node comms.

Comment: ok , i'm definitely going for the W5500 . thanks

Answer (score 3):

You say you need the maximum number of simultaneous links: 4 links (not 64 as you say). It's 4 because, at most, device A talks to device B, device C talks to device D, device E talks to device F, and device G talks to device H. That's 4 links.

One solution is a matrix switch (a.k.a. [crossbar switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossbar_switch)) that consists of 8 by 8 switches = 64 switches. Each switch handles 8 digital lines.

But a better solution is what the telephone company does: implement channels. In your case, 4 channels.

Each channel handles 2 links (8 digital lines) and consists of a 8:1 multiplexer to select the first of the 8 devices and a 1:8 demultiplexer to select the second of the 8 devices. Four channels handle all 4 simultaneous links.

[image: Selector]

Each box represents an 8:1 switch such as the 74HC4051, with a propagation delay of 4 ns.